# How to change the highlight color of the workspace chooser toolbar applet?

Tags: applet, appearance, workspaces

A recent update to Ubuntu changed the way the workspace chooser panel applet worked.  It used to highlight the choosen workspace as orange, and other workspaces would be not colored.  Now it is the reverse.  Is there a way to change this to set it back to the way it used to be?

The new scheme is counter intuitive to me, and even though I've been using it for months I just can't get used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those colours are part of the colour scheme provided by the desktop scheme. So the only solution I can think of is to go to System -> Preferences -> Appearance and change to a different desktop scheme or customise the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Appearance Preferences>Customize>Colors & see if you can change the color for tooltips. That might help you.....